# HTTP POST with node.js and request library isn't outputting anything

Tags: node.js, post, http-post, requestjs

I'm just testing to see if my POST request to a website works, but it isn't outputting anything. When I use RunKit, it shows an output, but not in my powershell. Am I doing something wrong or is there no output? How can I make it show the output? Here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'My_API_URL',
    { json: { "text":"this is my text" } },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest you, is to update your code like this and try again:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  uri: 'My_API_URL',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {
    "text":"this is my text"
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

Let me know if the result is the same.

Comment: The result is the same sadly. I don't know what is wrong. The URL I am outputting to is https://pastecode.xyz/api/create.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904808/posting-with-json-using-npm-request). You should do post requests like this:

```
var request = require('request');

var body = JSON.stringify({ 
    client_id: '0123456789abcdef', 
    client_secret: 'secret', 
    code: 'abcdef'
});

request.post({
    url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }},
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    }
);
```